# create column chart in highcharts dynamically from json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have the following json data

```
var json= {
    "PFTs_likely_to_change": [
        [16]
    ],
    "PFTs_likely_to_remain_unchanged": [
        [2]
    ]
}
```

This data is coming through url

```
var data=$.getJSON('{% url "PFTpercentChange" %}');
```

then I parse the json data

```
var json = JSON.parse(data);
```

Now I want to create column chart using highcharts.The code is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#container").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 600,
    height: 500

  });
  $("#btnclick").click(function() {
    $("#container").dialog("open");
    //var json = JSON.parse(data);
    var json = {
      "PFTs_likely_to_change": [
        [16]
      ],
      "PFTs_likely_to_remain_unchanged": [
        [2]
      ]
    };
    //var chart1; // globally available
    chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'column' // change with your choice
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Change in Plant Functional Types'
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: ['Change in Plant Functional Types']
          // Should be replace with JSON
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Percentage(%)'
        }
      },
      series: [{ //Should be replace with JSON
        name: 'PFTs likely to change',
        data: [88]
      }, {
        name: 'PFTs likely to remain unchanged',
        data: [12]
      }]
    });
  });
});
```

How can I do this dynamically?

Comment: can u please share the fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CPT6d/72/

Comment: `$.getJSON` returns an `jqXHR` object. You're trying to `JSON.parse` that object and it's working?

Comment: No Im not using JSON.parse. I have shared the fiddle. I read in some docs that we need to parse JSON when using external data. My problem is how to do this dynamically?

Comment: make sure u are getting data type is `string` or `Object`. If it is Object then use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))`

Comment: How can I access json data in line data: [88]

Comment: for example `json = {"prop": [1,2,3]}` then use `data: json.prop or json['prop']` instead of `[88]` in line `data:[88]`

Comment: In my case, when I give json["PFTs_likely_to_change"] or json.PFTs_likely_to_change, its not working

Comment: can u share the json

Comment: I have already shared var json= {
    "PFTs_likely_to_change": [
        [16]
    ],
    "PFTs_likely_to_remain_unchanged": [
        [2]
    ]
}

Comment: so i think ur json is stringified.(convert to object using) use JSON.parse(json) and use this.

Comment: Its not working. Only the dialog is opening

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/htoniv/CPT6d/77/

Comment: @Aparna check the fiddle in answer below

Answer (score 1):

**Update** [Fiddle with chart in dialog with dynamic json data](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/CPT6d/79/)

[Here is working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/CPT6d/78/)

have a separate div for popup/modal. Now put your highchart container div in it.
change your code to get series data dynamically as below code :

```
 var json= {
"PFTs_likely_to_change": [
    [16]
],
"PFTs_likely_to_remain_unchanged": [
    [2]
]
 }
var seriesData=[];
$.each(json,function(key,val){
console.log(key+"----key----and value"+val);
seriesData.push({name:key,data:val}); //put seriesData in chart's series
});
```